# Queryset to retrieve objects which include all of many-to-many relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Does anyone could help me with the following:

I have the following models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField()
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

Pretty simple.
Now I want to make queryset which will give me all Posts which include all
given tags.
For example. I have Post1 with tags: 'tag1', Post2 with 'tag2', and Post3 with tags: 'tag1' and 'tag2'. I want to get only Post3.

I figure out that it can be achieved by consequent filters like:

```
queryset = Post.object.filter(tag=1).filer(tag=2)
```

However, it is quite unacceptable if I want to retrieve the Post object passing a lot of tags(there will be a lot of chained filters)

Please let me now if some better approach exists.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A way of implementing Sagars solution in one query

```
Post.objects.filter(
    tag__in=tags
).annotate(
    matched_tags=Count(tag)
).filter(
    matched_tags=len(tags)
)
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

For querying the many to many fields you can use the following approach:

```
queryset=Posts.objects.filter(tag__in=[tag1,tag2])
```

This retrieve all the posts objects having tag1 and tag2.

Comment: try this:  t = Tag.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3])
 total_tags = len(t)

 posts = list()
 posts = Post.objects.all()
 for p in posts:
  post_tags = p.tag.filter(id__in=[1,2,3])
  if total_tags = len(post_tags):
   posts.append(p)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not good though but will work in your case, I hope you will get your desired solution.

```
t = Tag.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3])
total_tags = len(t)

posts = list()
posts = Post.objects.all()
for p in posts:
    post_tags = p.tag.filter(id__in=[1,2,3])
    if total_tags = len(post_tags):
        posts.append(p)
```

Comment: for perfect solution read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: Thanks, this solution works. But there are so many queries to db. I supposed that the task was quite trivial. Do I understand you correctly that in aggregation section of the doc there is a better solution?

Answer (score -1):

I think you could do it this way:

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(tag = Tag.objects.filter(id__in=(1,2)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like incorrect statement since in gives such an error:1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'. This is because 'tag =' expect one element

Comment: And variant Post.objects.filter(tag = (2,3)) gives only one object with tag = 2